# React Native app crashed after weird recursion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native app I have a `logIn` component, which one after successful response from API changes screen to `Feed`:

```
  navigate(component, type = 'FloatFromRight') {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component,
      index: 2,
      type
    })
  }

  logIn() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUser(this.state));
  }


componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps): void {
    if (nextProps.isFetching) return;
    if (Object.keys(nextProps.user).length) {
      this.navigate(Feed);
    }
  }
```

In `Feed` component I fetch feed like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchFeed());
  }
```

But I can't find how after successful `fetchFeed()` runs `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` again from my log in component. What's wrong here, where I did a mistake?

Comment: Is it because your login view is still on the stack (which it is, because your pushing a new component over it in the navigator) and then your using the same `isFetching` state variable for your login component and your feed component?

Comment: Oh, yeah! Thank you very much!